# How to pass 2d array from java to matlab(R2018b) using JMI package and get results back from matlab to java?

Tags: java, matlab

I want to implement SVD, PCA and LDA algorithms using java and matlab. I am extracting data and forming a 2-D matrix using java, which then I want to pass to matlab's svd, pca functions. However, I am getting error in matlab as "First input must be single or double."

I am establishing java-matlab communication as (using JMI package) -

```
 MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
 MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();
 String path ="cd(Matlab path)";
 proxy.eval(path);
```

For instance, my 2-D array is created like this -

```
double [][] A = new double[][] {{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0},{7.0,8.0,9.0}};
```

My matlab function is written as -

```
function svd1(A) 
    [U,S,V] = svd(A); 
end
```

Now, I am calling matlab function from java as -

```
proxy.feval("svd1",(Object) A);
```

This is working fine when I pass one dimensional array but failing in case of 2-D arrays.

Any pointers on how to pass 2-D array from java to matlab and how to get results back will be really helpful.